# Showing type error for css property for these two line that mention

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, error-handling, typeerror

Showing this error:
[image]

These two lines Showing type error for css property:

slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

showSlides(slideIndex);

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("projectSlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
  if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `slides` is undefined at the index `slideindex - 1`. So, what the error is essentially saying is, slides at that position do not exist, and since you are looking for the element at position 0, this means your array is empty.